# How to submit a form after confirming submit? jQuery, AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day, I have a simple html page containing this form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="details" modelAttribute="code">
  <form:input path="code"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

When I press the Submit button I need to check whether there are some records in the database for given code using jQuery AJAX. If yes then popup jQuery UI dialog to ask user whether he really wants to display record details (because it's a paid service). If he confirms I need to submit the form. This is my script on the html page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Bind an event handler to the submit event
  $('form#code').submit( function() {

    // Check whether there are some records in the DB using AJAX
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getResultCount',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: $("form#code").serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        if(result == 'null') {
          $('div#results').html('<p>No records found for ' + $('input#code').val() + '.</p>');
        } else {
          // At leat one record was found so ask the user
          $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            height: 240,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              "Display details": function() {
                // User confirmed, submit the form
                $('form#code').submit();
              },
              Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

When I press "Display details" button nothing happens. I think it is because I'm entering the same submit handler which returns false. How to solve it so that form submit is executed? Please advise.
Thank you in advance.
Vojtech

Comment: It does not make sense. You are submitting the form and than you are confirming sumbmitting the same form? Isn't it an infinite loop?  Baiscally it is: `$('form#code').submit( function() { $('form#code').submit() });`

Comment: @epascarello no; the form posts to `/details` and the AJAX request posts to `/getResultCount`

Comment: Yes, it is. And I'm looking for a way how to solve this situation.

Comment: @sholsinger, that has nothing to so with what I said...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$('form#code').submit();
```

to

```
$('form#code')[0].submit();
```

It will skip the jQuery onsubmit function.

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ax6m/

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple answer: Do not use `<input type="submit" ... />`.

You can instead use `<button onlick="handler()">Submit</button>`, where `handler()` is your function bound to the submit-event of the form in the above code. If your handler decides that the form should be submitted just submit it programmatically. Edit: Which is actually already in your code.

Comment: But what if user does not click the button but presses Enter key in the text input? I would like the form to react properly on Enter key as well.

Comment: Agree, this is a sound solution. `<input type="none" ... />` + binding in jquery/ajax code.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to wait for the `.ajax` to `succeed` since it is currently running in `async` mode.

So disable it using the `async` option on `ajax`.  [Documentation Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

### ANSWER SPECIFICALLY FOR YOU

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Bind an event handler to the submit event
    $('form#code').submit(function () {
        // Check whether there are some records in the DB using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getResultCount',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $("form#code").serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 'null') {
                    $('div#results').html('<p>No records found for ' + $('input#code').val() + '.</p>');

                    //No Records found, submitting!!
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // At leat one record was found so ask the user
                    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        height: 240,
                        width: 450,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Display details": function () {
                                // User confirmed, submit the form
                                return true;
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                                //TODO: Don't think you need this line?
                                $(this).dialog("close");

                                //CANCEL!!!
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //User skipped Dialog somehow...ignoring....DO NOT SUBMIT
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

***Note:** This will return true and false to continue the submit process to the server*